# Read from file and store to 2D array not displaying properly

Tags: c++

I'm tring to read a text file that's made out of 30x100 integers: https://pastebin.com/wemNrdMZ

For some reason it display perfectly if I read the file into a char data type. But when I change the data type to int the display becomes completely messed up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBxnZ.jpg

Here's my code:

```
int const row = 30;
int const colum = 100;
int map[row][colum];
fstream inFile;
inFile.open("map.txt"); //Located at the same location as .cpp file
if (inFile.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < colum; j++)
        {
            inFile >> map[i][j];
        }
    inFile.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "file not found" << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colum; j++)
    {
        cout << map[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

}

successful reading if I change from int to char: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Lds.jpg

Comment: What is `row`? What is `column`? Where is the [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please inline your image into the question and post a snippet of your input file as well. There are those of us who can't access your links

Comment: And note that the input file is not 30 lines of 100 numbers, it's 30 lines of 100 ***digits***. That you attempt to read as *decimal* integers, which will be read greedily (and lead to overflow).

Comment: You're not using the correct data type. You should be reading single chars. you had it right the first time. If you want integers (and I cannot fathom why it is needed) more work is involved, and frankly it isn't worth the trouble.